# Dificuldade ao carregar sections no cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, índices, uitableview

Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade na implementação de índices (A até Z) no meu app… 
Veja a estrutura abaixo, o que eu devo fazer para carregar corretamente o `indexPath.section`?:

```
struct EmployeeDetails {
    let functionary: String
    let imageFace: String
    let phone: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
    }
}
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""

        let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
        self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
    }
}

struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

Acredito que o erro esteja no `cellForRowAt` no `TableViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var employeesSearching = [Employee]()
var isSearching : Bool = false

let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()
var sections: [[AnyObject]] = []
var objects: [AnyObject] = [] {
    didSet {
        let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: UIApplicationShortcutItem.localizedTitle)
        sections = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)

        let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArray(from: objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
        for object in sortedObjects {
            let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: object, collationStringSelector: selector)
            sections[sectionNumber].append(object as AnyObject)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return sections.count }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isSearching ? employeesSearching.count : sections[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
    let entry = isSearching ? employeesSearching[indexPath.row] : Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]

    //sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]   ??? COMO ???

    cell.nameLabel.text = entry.name
    cell.positionLabel.text = entry.position

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return collation.sectionTitles[section]
}

override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return collation.sectionIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    return collation.section(forSectionIndexTitle: index)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if self.searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
        self.isSearching = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        self.isSearching = true
        self.employeesSearching.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchText = self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
        for employee in Shared.instance.employees {
            if employee.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil {
                self.employeesSearching.append(employee)
            }
        }
    }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Como eu faço para implementar `sections`, `[indexPath.section]` e `[indexPath.row]` na mesma linha de código neste caso?

Comment: troca pra `let t = dictionary["Details"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []` e tira o force cast `self.details = t.map( { EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0) } )`

Comment: @LeoDabus O app está rodando, mas a TableView está vazia. Eu não teria que inserir algo como `sections` ou `[indexPath.section]` no `cellForRowAt`? Se sim, **como**?

Comment: @LeoDabus, alguma ideia, camarada? ∴

Comment: o ideal é voce usar o tipo do object no seu array sections em vez de AnyObject para facilitar voce acessar as propriedades do elemento

Comment: @LeoDabus Fiz isso, ele pede pra coloca `cell` como `(entry as AnyObject)` e após isso ele mostra o erro: *Cannot assign value of type 'CGPoint!' to type 'String?'*

Comment: @LeoDabus, tentei também algo como `cell.nameLabel.text = entry[sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]].name`, mas ele não recebe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o ideal é que o seu employeesSearching seja um array bidimensional já organizado por pelas sections.

Ou seja, o employee que é da section 0 vai estar em employeesSearching[0][i], o que é da 1, vai estar na employeeSearching[1][i] e por aí vai...

Pega a sua lista, percorre ela organizando em um array bidimensional e depois você consegue, no cellForRowAt só fazer entry = employeesSearching[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].

Comment: Fiz o que você sugeriu. Mas também precisei alterar a `Struct Shared` para `var employees: [[Employee]] = []`. Daí inseri `[indexPath.section]` no `cellForRowAt`, tudo isso ficou 100%!! Porém na `func searchBar` ele está me retornando um erro que não consigo resolver -> Está dizendo que o **valor do tipo `[Employe]` não possui o membro `name`.** Editei a minha pergunta para você ver. O erro está na linha: `if employee.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil`. Desde já **MUITO** obrigado!

Comment: Tô do celular e não consegui achar a linha que você comentou. Mas pela mensagem de erro, parece que você pegou o employee como se fosse Employee, mas na verdade é um array de employee. Verifica de você esqueceu de pegar o employee pelo índice do section direitinho.